# Inserting json file into postgres with SQLAlchemy flask

Tags: json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to insert a json file into postgress db using flask/sqlalchemy however I'm  running into

```
TypeError: 'farmers' is an invalid keyword argument for Farmer
```

### This is my upload script:

```
import os
import flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask, jsonify, send_from_directory
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON

APP = Flask(__name__)
APP.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:admin@localhost:5432/flaskwebapp'
db = SQLAlchemy(APP)

class Farmers(db.Model):
    Farmers = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    W = db.Column(db.Integer)
    Z = db.Column(db.Integer)
    J1_I = db.Column(db.Integer)
        
def insert_data():
 
    f1 = Farmers(farmers={"farmers":[{"W":1000000,"Z":22758,"J1_I":0.66},{"W":3500000,"Z":21374,"J1_I":2.69},{"W":2500000,"Z":14321,"J1_I":0.76},{"W":2500000,"Z":14321,"J1_I":0.76}]})
    db.session.add(f1)
    db.session.commit()
    print('Data inserted to DB!')

insert_data()
```

This is the json file in question, however i dont think this is an issue as i'm able to read it in cmd:

```
{
    "farmers":[ {
"W":1000000,
"Z":22758,
"J1_I":0.66
},
{
"W":3500000,
"Z":21374,
"J1_I":2.69
},
{
"W":2500000,
"Z":14321,
"J1_I":0.76
},
{
"W":2500000,
"Z":14321,
"J1_I":0.76
}]}
```

Any ideas why i'm not able to upload the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model constructor won't accept a list, you need to pass each dictionary individually:

```py
farmer_data = {"farmers":[{"W":1000000,"Z":22758,"J1_I":0.66},{"W":3500000,"Z":21374,"J1_I":2.69},{"W":2500000,"Z":14321,"J1_I":0.76},{"W":2500000,"Z":14321,"J1_I":0.76}]}
farmers = [Farmer(**data) for data in farmer_data["farmers"]]
db.session.add_all(farmers)
db.session.commit()
```